# WordPress Filter: wp_authenticate_user not getting user data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, recaptcha

For a WordPress + WooCommerce setup, I'm trying to implement email activation and Google Captcha function on login using [`wp_authenticate_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/) filter, but the order of checking these are wrong.

**Ok scenario**

1. Blank username and password without Captcha submit > get the correct error saying *the password is blank*.
2. Invalid username without password and Captcha submit > correct error message saying *bad username or password*.
3. Valid username with a wrong password with Captcha submit > *bad username or password*

**Bad scenario**

1. valid username with a wrong password without Captcha submit > *Captcha error*
   (expecting bad username or password).

How can I change this to check Captcha after username and password validation?

**Note:**

If I switch email activated check to have more priority then I get that error on bad scenario.

**Captcha check**

```
function display_login_captcha() { ?>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_option('captcha_site_key'); ?>"></div>
<?php }
add_action( "login_form", "display_login_captcha" );

function verify_login_captcha($user,$password) {
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $recaptcha_secret = get_option('captcha_secret_key');
        $response = wp_remote_get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $recaptcha_secret ."&response=". $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $response = json_decode($response["body"], true);
        if (true == $response["success"]) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            return new WP_Error("Captcha Invalid", __(" Only 3 attemps allowed,  Are you Human? Please validate yourself"));
        }
    } else {
        return new WP_Error("Captcha Invalid", __(" Only 3 attemps allowed, It seems like we are having hard time identifying you as a human! If you are then enable JavaScript"));
    }
}
add_filter("wp_authenticate_user", "verify_login_captcha", 10, 2);
```

**Activation check**

```
function custom_authenticate_user($userdata) {
    $isActivated = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'is_activated', true);
    if (!$isActivated) {
        $userdata = new WP_Error(
                            'inkfool_confirmation_error',
                            __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> 111 <'.$userdata->id.'>Your account has to be activated before you can login. You can resend by clicking <a href="/sign-in/?u='.$userdata->ID.'">here</a>', 'inkfool' )
                        );
    }
    return $userdata;
}
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'custom_authenticate_user',11,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that validates the username/email is hooked to the [`autenticate`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/) filter with the priority `20`. And the hooks are added through `wp-includes/default-filters.php` as you can see below:

```
// Default authentication filters
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password',  20, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password',     20, 3 );
```

So if you want your custom validation functions to run **after** those default validations, then you should hook to the `authenticate` filter instead and use `20` (or a higher value - `21`, `30`, etc.) as the priority:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_login_captcha', 21, 3 );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_user', 21 );
```

And change your function declaration so that it looks like so, where the first parameter is *either* a `NULL` or `WP_User` instance on success:

```
function verify_login_captcha( $user, $username, $password ) {
  ...your validation...

  return $user; // You should return the WP_User instance or a WP_Error instance on error.
}

function custom_authenticate_user( $user ) {
  ...your validation...

  return $user; // You should return the WP_User instance or a WP_Error instance on error.
}
```

*PS: Make certain to check if the `$user` is a valid user object before accessing its properties and methods. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/#parameters) for more details.* E.g.:

```
function custom_authenticate_user( $user ) {
  if ( ! $user ) {
    return $user;
  }

  ...
}
```